# What does this SandCastle Help File Builder error mean?

Tags: sandcastle

I'm trying to generate a help file using SandCastle Help File builder in msbuild but I am getting the following error:

SandcastleBuilder.Utils.BuilderException: Invalid or missing SchemaVersion

What does it mean? And how can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/f6258ea1-df3f-4397-81e4-3e0a39abcdc2.htm) of any help?

Comment: Please consider expanding this to an actual answer instead of a link-only one.